# Panel not correctly repainting image in Java?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, mouseevent, graphics2d

Right now I am trying to get it so whenever I click inside of the oval that I have painted, and drag the mouse it will move positions by repainting. However, even though the MouseEvents are being detected correctly, the oval image is not updating. I am confused to why that is. Here is the code that deals with the oval, MouseEvents, and updating:

```
public class DrawOval extends JPanel {
private int size = 50;
private int locX = 0; //vector points
private int locY = 0;
private boolean isPressed = false;
private Shape oval = new Ellipse2D.Double(locX, locY, size, size * 2);

public DrawOval(int size){
    this.size = size;
    Dimension dims = new Dimension(size, size);
    setPreferredSize(dims);
    setMaximumSize(dims);
    setMinimumSize(dims);

    MouseAdapter m = new MouseAdapter(){
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){
            isPressed = false;
            update(e);
            System.out.println("Mouse is released!");
        }

        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
            isPressed = true;
            update(e);
            System.out.println("Mouse is pressed!");
        }

        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e){
            if(isPressed){
                update(e);
                System.out.println("Mouse is dragged!");
            }
        }

        public void update(MouseEvent e){
            System.out.println("X: " + e.getX() + ", Y: " + e.getY());
            if(oval.contains(e.getX(), e.getY())){
                setX(e.getX()); setY(e.getY());
                repaint();
            }
            //does not update if the mouses click coordinates are outside of the oval
        }
    };
    addMouseListener(m); //for pressing and releasing
    addMouseMotionListener(m); //for dragging
}

public void setX(int _x){
    this.locX = _x;
}
public void setY(int _y){
    this.locY = _y;
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g2.fill(oval);
}
}
```

I cannot figure out why it is not updating correctly. I had it partially working before, but it would update all the time, even if where the user clicked was not within the oval.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

I think doing `setX` and `setY` you forget to update `x` and `y` in your `oval`. You have at least three options:

1) recreate `Ellipse2D.Double` every time you change `this.locX` and `this.locY`.

2) expect that your `oval` is created with `x=0, y=0` once and for all, check mouse event switching to relative coordinates (`if(oval.contains(e.getX() - locX, e.getY() - locY)){...}`) and draw your `oval` using `AffineTransform` by `g2.transform(...)`.

3) Declare oval as `Ellipse2D.Double oval = new Ellipse2D.Double(...);` and then you can change its `x` and `y` directly cause they're public:

```
    oval.x = this.locX;
    oval.y = this.locY;
```